# Ionic 3 Checkbox Only One Select

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-list>
  Adres Seç
  <ion-item *ngFor="let adres of adresler" >
    <ion-label>{{adres.baslik}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="dark"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

There is my codes. i want to pick only 1 checkbox, how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you want to pick one checkbox"?

Comment: there is more than one checkboxes, and i want to pick only one, if i have checked one checkbox, another checkboxes will not check

Comment: So, when you check a single checkbox, others are getting checked automatcally?

Comment: it shouldn't be so hard to understand. there is four checkboxes, Red, Green,Yellow,Blue, i want to pick only one, if i picked Red, and if i will check Blue, uncheck Red, check Blue, alter if i check Yellow, uncheck Blue , check Yellow, please understan

Comment: Why not use [radio-buttons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/)?

Comment: As suggested by @robbannn use radio-buttons. From docs: `If a radio button is not placed in a group, they will all have the ability to be checked at the same time.`

Comment: i have used radio-buttons thanks